# Can I view a .m || .h file on a PC, with correct text spacing?

Tags: xcode, text-formatting

I am building a 'fairly' complicated iPhone program using Xcode.  Unfortunately I am limited to program only during normal-people hours-- when I have access to a Mac, at my work place.  As much as I like the idea of keeping my work @ work, I'm finding that it's difficult to code a big project when I'm not constantly thinking about it and looking at it.

Therefore, if anybody knows a way that I could **view** my `.m` files on my pc, I would be very grateful to hear how this could be!  Let me be clear: I don't want to compile/build on this pc.  Alls-I-wants-to-do is get the visual of the text on my screen AND to do this in a way that my white-space is preserved!

As we all know, `.h` is C++ talk, and it seems like it would be viewable (with the appropriate spacing) in any C++ development-program; But, that doesn't seem to be the case.  Is this at all possible to read both `.h` and `.m` files on a pc?

Answer (score 0):

.m files are just text files. You can open them in any text editor. The only issue I can think of is text editors that default to rendering tabs at 8 spaces with no way to configure this, but any programmer's text editor will give you control over it. I'm not a Windows guy but I imagine [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or any number of other editors would fit the bill.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
That -was- my understanding of it....
But I was just attempting this: I renamed the files from
._SomeCoolObject.m -> ._SomeCoolObject.txt and
._SomeCoolObject.h -> ._SomeCoolObjectHeader.txt

and when I opened both, I got some insane nonsense.  Unrecognizable jibberish txt.  

I'm not sure what "._" is doing, prefixing all my classes; I'm suspicious of it...

Comment: ._* files are the "Finder info" files for your Mac. They contain things like the icon artwork, notes, colour highlighting labels, and such. You can ignore them on Linux | Windows. (They *should* be hidden from your file manager, because they start with a ".", but I gather the Windows Explorer doesn't always do so.)

Comment: @EthanSherr: You're rather confused. `._foo` is a metadata file that contains the resource fork and extended attributes for the file `foo`. On the native Mac filesystem (HFS+) this information is actually stored in the filesystem as data explicitly associated with the file `foo`, but on filesystems that don't support this (e.g. `NFS` or other non-Mac filesystems) it's stored in the sidecar file `._foo`. You can safely ignore this file on Windows. The file you should be editing is called `SomeCoolObject.m`.

Answer (score 0):

.m file is just a text file. Any text editor will open them just fine.

I recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as it has decent Objective-C syntax highlighter.

Comment: Well-- Alright, I actually have tried to open them as .txt's, as I describe above, but the resulting characters are jibberish-- (maybe the code got corrupted?)  I'll download Notepad++ in the meanwhile, to check things out. --thanks

Comment: Turns out, filenames starting with "._" are um... bad.  
Notepad++ is great, and can open .m and .h files beautifully, thanks Kevin && Sosborn

Answer (score 0):

Also, for what it's worth, you can load Objective C files in Emacs or Eclipse, both of which are cross-platform (Linux, MacOS, Windows, whatever); understand Objective-C syntax; and (if you load GCC, the Gnu Compiler Collection) can compile any files that don't require Apple Frameworks. (I imagine that most of your iPhone app will have Apple Frameworks needed to actually compile, though…)

(As noted in my other comment, ignore the ._* files on a non-MacOS system.)

Answer (score 0):

The .m files are just Obj-C files, they are exactly the same format as any `.c` or `.c++` file, and will open perfectly fine in any good text editor (Notepad++ seems popular). You do not need to rename the file to end in `.txt` or anything, just leave it as `.m` and open it up in Notepad++.

Chances are the encoding is UTF-8, you may need to configure your windows editor to use this encoding by default. You should also configure it to use "UNIX" newlines (`\n`).

If your editor of choice doesn't recognise the file type and automatically do syntax highlighting, try setting it to use C++ as the language. It's not the same language as Obj-C, but close enough to do the job.

The files who's name begins with `._` are not anything that can be opened on a PC. They're the "resource fork" of the file with the same name, and are typically used to store data other than the file's actual content. Resource forks do not exist on a PC filesystem, so Mac OS makes the `._` files instead.

They are also officially deprecated by apple, something like **ten years ago** and you should try to track down what program is creating `._` files and submit a bug report, asking them to update their program to stop creating them please.

It is usually safe to delete any file with `._` in the name, but not always. In your case, I'm guessing they contain the exact window position from the last time you opened the file on a mac, or the cursor location. There are better ways to store that info, so I'd file a bug report.